# Can I have a continuous animation for a given state in Angular4

Tags: angular, html, animation, css-animations

Here is the sample code from https://angular.io/guide/animations

```js
  animations: [
    trigger('heroState', [
      state('inactive', style({
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
        transform: 'scale(1)',
      })),
      state('active',   style({
        backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
        transform: 'scale(1.1)'
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
```

The states specify an end style and the transition specifies the animation. I want a continuous animation on a specific state (say active) like https://www.kirupa.com/html5/examples/iphone_ipad_icon_wobble.htm

Is this possible using Angular 4 animations or would I need to do a plain CSS animation (https://www.kirupa.com/html5/creating_the_ios_icon_jiggle_wobble_effect_in_css.htm)

Comment: Would it be ok to do in traditional css animation way?

Comment: I have specified a link that does is it in the traditional way. I wanted to know if this is possible in Angular 4 or does it only support one time transition animation